# Video background causing sliding nav to glitch?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, z-index

I am working on a site which has a full page video background. There is a nav that slides out (using jQuery UI) from the left when the user scrolls down to the content of the site.

Here is the site in progress: http://www.nolanmanning.com/ratcaveV12

As you can see, the nav slides out, but it does not immediately appear above everything else. I am assuming that this is because of something wrong that I am doing with z-indexes, but I don't know. If I remove the sliding effect and just have the nav visible at all times, the problem goes away.

If someone can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
nav {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 280px;
  background: #222;
  text-align: right;

  z-index: 3; /* change to 3 */
}

article {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #111;
  padding: 50px 50px 50px 330px;

  position: relative; /* added */
  z-index: 2; /* added */
}

#top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  position: relative; /* added */
  z-index: 1; /* added */
}
```

I suggest you change the guy's padding top to the following:

```
#top h1 {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

That should sort out your z-index issue.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I can't thank you enough. Z-indexes have been one thing that has constantly confused me. Do you happen to know any good resources that might help me get the hang of them?